# Do I need Nginx with Gunicorn if I am not serving any static content?

Tags: python, django, nginx, django-rest-framework, gunicorn

In a typical python server setup it is recommended to have Nginx web server serve the static content and proxy the dynamic requests to  Gunicorn app server. 
Now if I am not serving any static content through my python application do I still need Nginx in front of Gunicorn ? What would be the advantages ? 
Detailed explanation would be really appreciated.

All the static content is served through CDN and the backend server will only need to serve the APIs(REST). So when I will only server dynamic content, will I need to have Nginx ? Does it have any advantage in case of high load etc.

Comment: Normally you'd do that if you want to expose a minimum API for development purposes, if you're providing a full Webapp you will sooner or later need to serve static files, apart from that, you can ignore Gunicorn if your plan is to serve a small TCP server for example.

Comment: @AlejandroVicaria I was referring to full production mode. Actually all the static content is served through CDN and the backend server will only need to serve the APIs(REST). So when I will only server dynamic content, will I need to have Nginx ? Does it have any advantage in case of high load etc ?

Comment: In my experience, although it is technically best practice to be using nginx, you don't need it. I guess nginx is more adept at handling incoming requests from the world, and gunicorn is better at serving your app. But really the rest of your system architecture should be enough that your not depending on solely these factors. For example, in case of high load, you can just have more instances of your application running behind a load balancer. Don't give yourself more to maintain.

Comment: If you use SSL/TLS I would recommend to use nginx since it's more battle tested then any python library, and it's probably much more efficient. If not then you don't have to, but not using SSL/TLS is really not recommend

Answer (score 37):

It is [recommended in Gunicorn docs](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html) to run it behind a proxy server.

Technically, you don't really *need* Nginx.

**BUT** it's the Internet: your server will receive plenty of malformed HTTP requests which are made by bots and vulnerability scanner scripts. Now, your Gunicorn process will be busy parsing and dealing with these requests instead of serving genuine clients.

With Nginx in front, it will terminate these requests without forwarding to your Gunicorn backend.

Most of these bots make requests to your IP address, instead of your domain name. So it's really easy to configure Nginx to ignore requests made to IP address and only serve requests made to your domain. This is far more secure and faster than relying on Django's `ALLOWED_HOSTS` settings.

Also, it's much easier to find resources for Nginx about protecting your server, like blacklisting rogue IP addresses or user agents, etc. Compare these two google searches: [nginx ban ip](https://www.google.com/search?q=nginx+ban+ip) vs [gunicorn ban ip](https://www.google.com/search?q=gunicorn+ban+ip). You can see Nginx search has more resources.

If you're worried about performance, then rest assured Nginx will not be the bottleneck. If you really want to optimise performance, database querying will be the first place to start.

Comment: Would you recommend it if using Gunicorn specifically for an API that was proxied from API Gateway?  If you have throttling, schema validation, and other protections in place, it seems like nginx would just be an added headache for that.

Comment: @reactive-core Yes, it's even recommended in [Gunicorn's docs](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html). Also, Nginx has a lot more features such as limiting request body size, closing slow connections (to avoid slow loris attacks) etc. You can't do this in Gunicorn.

Answer (score 2):

No, I no longer deploy nginx specifically for the python app. I may have an application load balancer / nginx in the path to split requests to other apps, but not for load management. If using asyncio based systems, I typically don't even use an app server (uwsgi/gunicorn). This is including apps with very high throughput. Every layer of reverse-proxy / layer-7 load balancing will add a touch of latency- don't add it if you don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you don't use NGINX for serving static assets [putting `gunicorn` behind a proxy server is the recommended setup](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html#deploying-gunicorn).

For example, putting `gunicorn` behind a proxy will allow to add some back pressure to your system in order to protect you from attacks such as [Slowloris](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowloris).

Comment: Thanks for that - didnt know about Slowloris. However, I would use Cloudflare as a proxy server, which includes (besides a CDN also) protection against this. Do you think that in that case, I would be fine without an additional nginx between Cloudflare and `gunicorn` ?

Comment: @tyrex Nginx is pretty easy to set up, so I don't think it's a big deal to go through a major effort to avoid it. All you have to do is set up the config file and everything is all good.